# Como faço para gerar um numero negativo aleatório?

Tags: java, random

Não consigo gerar um número aleatório que seja negativo, por exemplo menor que 0

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/numeros-aleatorios-em-java-a-classe-java-util-random/26355      gere um número aleatório , multiplique por -1.

Comment: obrigado, deu certo

Comment: @Motta responde.

Comment: @Motta seria bom colocar como resposta oficial, se pudesse com uma linha de exemplo. Acho mais correto positivar a sua solução e fechar o assunto, assim o Vitor poderia marcar a sua como resolvida, já que foi você que solucionou realmente. E o exemplo ajudaria outros visitantes.

Comment: O Daniel Omnine já o fez @Bacco.

Comment: @Motta quando comentei ainda não tinha a dele. Realmente teria sido melhor a sua por uma questão de ética, de qq forma se tiver uma alternativa enxuta e objetiva, conte com meu voto.

Comment: Sempre lembrando que em geral as funções do tipo "random" geram um número pseudo-aleatório que em algumas aplicações não são recomendadas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

int n = (rand.nextInt(50) + 1) * -1;
```

O exemplo acima é meramente didático.

O número 50 define o range e foi colocado para fins de demonstração. Será gerado um número aleatório entre 0 e 49. Por isso somamos +1 para que os números sejam entre 1 e 50.

Do resultado obtido, multiplica-se por -1 pois na matemática um número positivo multiplicado por um número negativo torna-se negativo. Isso aprendemos no primário escolar.

Com isso, obtém-se o resultado esperado. Um número negativo aleatório.

Existem, obviamente, outras formas de chegar ao mesmo resultado. O exemplo acima é meramente ilustrativo. Não quer dizer que seja o melhor ou a única forma.

Adapte o exemplo conforme a sua necessidade.

Lembrando que no JAVA podemos também converter de uma forma mais resumida:

```
n = 10;
n = -n;  // Resultado: -10
```

Answer (score 3):

Gere um número positivo e o multiplique por -1;

Answer (score 2):

Gere um número positivo normalmente e então multiplique por -1.

Comment: Fiz confusão, ja editei e consertei.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção. :-)

Comment: @PauloSantos quem fez confusão não foi o Marcio? Já que ele é o autor desta resposta?